# Java/MongoDB searchQuery changes date

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I make 2 dates with this code, when I pass them to a BasicDBObject, one hour is subtracted of the dates:

```
public static Date hoursBack(int hours){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    cal.setTime(DateCreator.currentDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1*hours);

    return cal.getTime();
}
Date date1 = hoursBack(1);
Date date2 = hoursBack(2);

System.out.println(date1.toString());
// Wed Nov 08 09:36:44 CET 2017
System.out.println(date2.toString());
// Wed Nov 08 10:36:44 CET 2017
```

Then I pass these dates to BasicDBObjects

```
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("timeStamp", new BasicDBObject("$gte", date1)));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("timeStamp", new BasicDBObject("$lte", date2)));

BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put("$and", obj);

System.out.println(searchQuery.toString());
// "$and" : [ { "timeStamp" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2017-11-08T08:36:44.232Z"}}} , { "timeStamp" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2017-11-08T09:36:44.232Z"}}}]
```

In the searchquery, BasicDBObject subtracted one hour of the dates.

Why does it happen? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Are these two pieces of code from different projects, running on different machines? Try passing your jvm this parameter: -Duser.timezone=Europe/Amsterdam . There must be a mix up with your timezones

Comment: It seems from your firt snippet that 1 hour ago was 9:36 in Amsterdam, and 2 hours ago was 10:36. This can’t be so.

Comment: I don’t see one hour subtracted, Amsterdam is 1 hour ahead of UTC. The `Z` in `2017-11-08T08:36:44.232Z` means UTC, so this time is exactly equivalent to `2017-11-08T09:36:44.232+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]`, the time you started out from.

Comment: Any reason you are still using the outdated classes `Calendar` and `Date`? Even if a `BasicDBObject` needs a `Date` object (which I don’t know), you may still use the modern Java date and time API for calculating the right date-time to pass to it.

Comment: @AlexP. It is on the same machine: BasicDBObject uses the epoch of the Date Object.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, made a fault in copy/pasting

Comment: So I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47176485/edit) and correct the copy/pasting. You may also want to word-wrap the line containing the output from `System.out.println(searchQuery.toString());` so we readily see that both dates are there (I am still sceptical about any one hour being added anywhere).

Comment: Good that you solved it (I saw [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197489/5772882)). I am still wondering if you could store a modern `java.time.Instant` into your `BasicDBObject` rather than an old-fashioned `Date`. Even if a `Date` was needed, it would be cleaner and more future-proof to get it from `Date.from(Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))`.

Comment: @OleV.V. There was no good reason for using it like I did. Since I rebuild it, I go use your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it, BasicDBObject uses the epoch of a Date Object. There are many questions why Date.toString() gives another time then the epoch of the Date object. 
.toString() uses the TimeZone, epoch of course not, so I've to fix it with epoch times.